# How to set ALLOWED_HOSTS Django setting in production when using Docker?

Tags: django, docker

I always set my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` from an environment variable in Django. In my development `.env` I always set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=.localhost,.127.0.0.1` and in production `ALLOWED_HOSTS=mydomain.dom,my_ip_address`

Now I am currently getting acquainted with Docker, and the question is what is the value of the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in production. Should it remain as localhost, since I understand localhost will refer to the host container or should I set it as my domain. I am using Nginx for reverse proxy to forward requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set it to your domain. `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is used to determine whether the request originated from the correct domain name.

If you look at [the docs for ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts), you'll see that it is compared to the request's `Host` header, which is set by the User agent of the person visiting your site.

So although the Docker container is serving to it's own localhost, the request is originating from `example.com`

Check out [this part of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/security/#host-header-validation) to see exactly why host header validation is necessary, and you will probably better understand the purpose of `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Comment: Thanks. I also remembered I can make use of `/etc/hosts`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57937075/3247914

Answer (score 1):

You can just use your regular domain/IP address. ALLOWED_HOSTS has to do with the headers of the user matching the IP of the server. The internal mechanics on the server are not the concern of it.

`ALLOWED_HOSTS=mydomain.dom,my_ip_address`

Is what you should go with.

Comment: Thanks.I also remembered I can make use of `/etc/hosts`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57937075/3247914

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers and I did confirm its true. I would like to add that I also remembered that this can be confirmed by adding your domain to `/etc/hosts` pointing to `127.0.0.1`. If the domain is not included in `/etc/hosts`, Django will throw a debug error telling you that the domain is not added to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Answer (score 1):

while using Docker, when you are using a WebServer like Nginx or Apache, setting configs for that server(Nginx,Apache,...) , you should choose a name for your server like below, for example in nginx.conf >>>

```
    server {
       listen       80;
       listen       [::]:80;
       server_name  localhost;
       root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

this config file will map **localhost** to your docker machine IP address,
you can confirm that by running this command inside your docker container

```
   cat /etc/hosts
```

in the output you should see something like this >

```
127.21.0.2   localhost
```

which 127.21.0.2 is ip address of the container which probably is something different for you

now inside Django project, change **settings.py** like below >

```
import socket
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [socket.gethostbyname('localhost')]
```

this way you can set **ALLOWED_HOSTS** dynamically and docker contaier ip changes will be managed by container host resolver.
note that setting **ALLOWED_HOSTS** to * is not a good idea :) 
this method will also works for **uwsgi**, **gunicorn** and any other wsgi